# Webview loads page incorrectly on android versions lower than 4.0

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to display a result webpage in a Webview and I'm getting a weird result on Android version lower than 4.0. I have a print screen with what the difference is.

It displays correctly on versions newer than 4.0 and it works fine on my Galaxy S2 but it displays wrong on 2 Samsung phones with Android 2.2 and 2.3 and on the emulator. I tried an emulator with Android 3.0 and I had the same result. As a note, the webpage result works fine on the browser and I have a feeling that the website does some redirects, in case that helps.

Here is the code I'm using to load the page:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    // Show the web page
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, MainActivity.content, "text/html",
            "UTF-8", null);

}
```

And the [image](http://oi57.tinypic.com/21lu921.jpg).

Any ideas why it doesn't work the same on all Android versions?

**UPDATE**
It's official, I have tried loading the website URL using multiple versions of WebViews, with different settings and the website just doesn't load correctly on devices with Android version older than 4. I'm stuck.

**UPDATE 1**

I noticed that on older versions it's not that it doesn't load correctly the page, the problem is that it tries to load the web version of the page and not the mobile version. I tried changing the user agent but it made no difference.

**UPDATE 2**

I tried almost all I could find on the site about WebViews and loading content and I can't figure out what the problem is. This is my code now, although it works the same only with java script enabled.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.setPersistentDrawingCache(0);
    webView.setInitialScale(1);
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

    String webData = MainActivity.content;

    webData = webData.replace("#", "%23");
    webData = webData.replace("%", "%25");
    webData = webData.replace("\\", "%27");
    webData = webData.replace("?", "%3f");
    webView.getSettings()
            .setUserAgentString(
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");

    webView.loadData(webData, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);

}

// webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(MainActivity.url, MainActivity.content,
// "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

// webView.loadData(MainActivity.content, "text/html; charset=utf-8",
// "UTF-8");
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Also, if it will help, this is the code for how I get the HTTP Post response that I use to display in the webview:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.fernbus24.de/bus-"
                + vonCopy + "-" + nachCopy);
        url = "http://www.fernbus24.de/bus-" + vonCopy + "-" + nachCopy;

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_searchbox",
                "d5ed667846"));

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("von", von));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nach", nach));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("datum", datum));
        // etc...
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
            Log.i("Test", "response status"
                    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(is);

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    inputStreamReader);

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String bufferedStrChunk = null;

            while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
            }

            content = stringBuilder.toString();

            Log.i("Test", "content is " + content);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**UPDATE 3**

I have tried setting webView.setInitialScale(50); and I am getting this:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried

```
webView.setInitialScale(50);
```

Comment: Yes, I have wrote in UPDATE 3 the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
Webview webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);


    wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    wb.loadUrl("URL");
```

if it doesn't work, please write your url then i will try it.

Comment: I can't use getURL because I am loading a webpage result in another Activity and passing it to this WebView.

Comment: I tried and I got exactly the same result after searching. The url is: http://www.fernbus24.de/