# Why is Android WebView loading webpage differently than the default browser?

Tags: android, webview

I'm having a problem related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450309/webview-loads-page-incorrectly-on-android-versions-lower-than-4-0). Basically, the same WebView displays differently on Android 2.2 and Android 4.0. In Android 4.0 it displays the mobile version of the website, while in 2.2 it displays the web version of it. Also, in the default web browser on Android 2.2 it displays the mobile version like it should. Is this a known bug? I have tried different settings for the webview so far but I always get this problem, on real devices and in the emulator.

I have attached 2 screens to see the difference. And here is the code. Note that I have tested pretty much all the combinations for the settings and to no use. 
`

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.setInitialScale(1);
    webView.getSettings()
            .setUserAgentString(
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.fernbus24.de/");

}`
```

Why is the display different? What does the WebView on Android 4.0 have that the other one doesn't?

[image][image]

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was going on? If you could write an answer to your question I'd really appreciate it

Comment: Check below for my answer. The website was not recognizing some devices as mobile and it was sending the desktop version of the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an Android bug, it's the website and the way it recognizes mobile devices. I tried google.com and facebook.com and they loaded the mobile version without problems.

Comment: No, they did not. Android GoogleChrome shows search pages differently than WebView.